# max of a convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

This may be an obvious question for some: suppose $f$ is a convex function. I would like to solve the problem

$$\max f(x) \\
\text{s.t. }x \in \Omega$$

where $\Omega$ is a regular (say, satisfying MFCQ) convex set. Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

I know how to solve the min problem using KKT condition. But I am unclear about the max case because the negative of $f$ is no longer a convex function. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If $\Omega$ is compact and convex, convex $f$ is maximized at an extreme point of $\Omega$; this sometimes cuts down the possibilities in a useful way.